# Include lib to javascript file on nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, include

I have a js file, on a Node.js server, that generate some text file for me. 
How i can include a lib like this `https://somedomain.com/somelib.js;` ?
I try

```
module.exports = myLib;
var myLibVar = require('https://somedomain.com/somelib.js').myLib;
```

but it's doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is help for me! js file include to my file.
http://www.scriptol.com/javascript/include.php